# JavaScript Valida Data de Nascimento e Bloquear Mesmo Ano

Tags: javascript, data

Preciso de um Javascript que Bloquei colocar data com o mesmo ano atual. Para Campo Data de nascimento. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Para o campo:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <label for="dataNasc" class="control-label"> Data de Nascimento</label>
                                        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="dataNasc" id="dataNasc"/>
                                    </div>
```

Comment: Você tentou usar o datepicker do Jquery UI ou onde você utiliza não pode utilizá-lo? [https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Comment: Não é javascript, mas você pode colocar manualmente:
  <input type="date" name="bday" max="2016-12-31"> o atributo max

Comment: Já pensei nessa possibilidade, mas eu preciso de algo mais automático.

Comment: Já automatizei na resposta abaixo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imaginemos que tem isto no HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="date_start">
```

No javascript temos isto:

```
var date = new Date(), y = date.getFullYear(), m = date.getMonth();
var fSDate = new Date(y, m, 1);
var fEDate = new Date(y - 1, m + 1, 0);

$.datepicker.setDefaults({
    changeMonth: false,
    changeYear: false,
    showOtherMonths: false,
    yearRange: '-0:+0',
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    defaultDate: +0, //30 days ago
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    minDate: fSDate, 
    maxDate: fEDate,
    showAnim: 'fadeIn',
    showButtonPanel: false
});

$('#date_start').datepicker();
```

Preste atenção no `fSDate` e `fEDate` e repare como pode definir os limites para o ano, mês e dia usando um pouco de lógica. Eu já subtraí um ano no `fEDate` e ele só vai mostrar no máximo 2016.

Veja [este exemplo online](http://jsfiddle.net/SMjcb/1/) no JSFiddle. Este exemplo é óptimo para você ver tudo o que pode mudar até obter o resultado desejado. Brinque um pouco com esse fiddler até dominar esse `datepicker()`.

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigada!!

Comment: Ainda bem, foi a minha primeira resposta aqui no SO que serviu de alguma coisa haha

Answer (score 2):

```js
 var data = new Date(new Date().getFullYear() - 1, 11, 31).toISOString().slice(0,10);
document.getElementsByName("dataNasc")[0].setAttribute("max", data);
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <label for="dataNasc" class="control-label"> Data de Nascimento</label>
                                        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="dataNasc" id="dataNasc"/>
                                    </div>
```

Comment: Obrigada, Gabriel!!